# Display Custom Icon in SAP GUI

Tags: abap, sap-gui

is it possible to create a custom icon and display it in SAP GUI classic dynpro? I would need to display it in the toolbar of my application - if possible.

Comment: SAP GUI is a very old technology. You can't change the style of any control at all. There are exceptions with the HTML control, image control, but the styles of the simple SAP GUI built-in controls cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about making your OWN icon, not using one of SAP's, then I don't think that is possible, because icons are a part of your SAPGui installation. Even if you uploaded an icon successfully (`SE78` or `RSTXLDMC`), it would only work for you, and only work until you update or reinstall your SAPGui. Hence you wouldn't be able to create a custom icon for all users.

Comment: it seems like you are right. I had a look at transaction icon and SE78 - both couldn't help me.Thanks!

Comment: Transaction `SE78` and program `RSTXLDMC` are used to upload images for SAPScript forms and Smart Forms (printing, essentially). I don't see any relationship with SAP GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible with the transaction ICON. Afterwards I think it should be possible to add it with the method add_function:

```
data:  l_icon       type string.



l_icon = icon_green_light.     "<--  Icon from type-pool.

try.
  lr_functions->add_function(
    name     = 'MYFUNCTION'
    icon     = l_icon
    text     = l_text
    tooltip  = l_text
    position = if_salv_c_function_position=>right_of_salv_functions ).
  catch cx_salv_existing cx_salv_wrong_call.
endtry.
```

Comment: Hi, the coding was not the problem for me - only how to add the icon into the system. but as Legxis already said, it seems like it is not possible to do that. - Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Sasku ahh ok I thought that you had a custom icon that you wanted for your SAPgui but you couldn't get it displayed in your toolbar. Unfortunately Legxis is right here if you want a custom icon for everyone it is not possible. you will have to reuse one from SAP.